# How to Virtualize a 3d matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How to graphically represent 3d matrix with its values in matlab , i don't get any luck finding something similar to it , except some of SO question did mentioned about virtual representation of 1D and 2D matrix, but not 3D matrices.

I am curious how to achieve 3D virtual figure with values in matlab ?

Comment: You mean how to make a hologram in MATLAB?

Comment: What are your dimensions of the 3d matrix? as 3xn ?

Comment: it is matrix of 200*200*3

Comment: with that you can treat it as an RGB image.